# How to stop users from using previous versions of my android Application

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, admob

I have a game on Google Play Store with Admob Ads. Recently I received a mail that my Admob account has been disabled. I believe that my account was disabled because I used Interstitial ads in place of rewarded ads to reward my users. Now I have updated my game and have removed those interstitial ads, but those users who are still using previous version of my game can access those ads. I want users to update the game and disable previous verisons of the game.

I have not linked firebase with my game.

Answer (score 1):

Did you implement a connection to your webservices checking the correct version of the game? You need to check the version during the game loading and show a popup with the information.

If you didn't implement something like that seems you won't be able to advise your users to update the game or block the access to the game, if the game have a login you could just send an email with the information...

Comment: Yes that's exactly what i'm doing in my app.And you can also send push notification to the users notifying them to update the app.

Comment: You can't force someone to update the app, you can block the app to the people who isn't updated.

Other way is the assets bundles but they are more focussed giving more content to the game.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, the only way to do this is invent a time machine and go back and change the old versions of your game. There are a few things you can which could help:

- Update your game (which you've already done)
- Make sure your new version of your game has something like [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/) so if this happens again in future, next time you have a solution to disable the game (but you can't go back to do this for an old version)
- Disable your original Admob account, and use a new Admob account in your update (that way users on the old version won't get the problematic Ads)

None of these are perfect.